# Multiplying two pandas.core.series.Series result in 1 additional row. Why?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have two series of type pandas.core.series.Series, with an index of timestamps named unixTime  and an unnamed data column of float64. Both columns have **8760 rows**.

I multiply these columns with *

The first five, and last five rows are as expected: correct timestamp, and correct numbers.

BUT: **I started with two columns with 8760 rows. I now have 8761 rows. Why?**

(I create the "columns"/ arrays with pd.loc[:, "NamedColumn"])
(The first five and last five timestamps are identical in both series - and probably all the ones in between)

Answer (score 0):

You have one index that exists in only one dataframe. To find it, use:

```
df1.index.symmetric_difference(df2.index)
```

Comment: Thanks! I do.                                   .

Comment: Did you find the difference between your 2 dataframes?

Comment: I still have a conundrum.
I get the result that unixTime 1572138000000, ('2019-10-27 01:00:00',) is missing from series A. When I check - yes, it's missing.

But both data series start with a number for 23:00 on december 31st, and end with an entry for 22:00 on december 31st the next year. This should result in 8760 rows, which they have. I'm wondering what can be wrong. Series A must have a double entry somewhere.

I'll try checking that the index contains an entry every hour, as it should.

Comment: This is the DST datetime.